# Swift: Help troubleshoot Segue data from one view to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

Hi I am very new to Swift. I have watched several different videos and tutorials on youtube and I am unable to identify what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to take the data from a check-in view and segue it to the summary view. The code runs, and I am able to move through the app, but the data does not move. Below is the code for the two different swift files. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Check-In:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VieNewCheckIN : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var SWR: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ModelNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var SerialNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Notes: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let viewnewsummary = segue.destination as? ViewNewSummary else { return }
        viewnewsummary.NotesValue = Notes.text
        viewnewsummary.SerialNumberValue = SerialNumber.text
        viewnewsummary.ModelNumberValue = ModelNumber.text
    }
}
```

---

Summary:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewNewSummary : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var FirstNameLabel: UILabel!
    var FirstNameValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var LastNameLabel: UILabel!
    var LastNameValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var IDLabel: UILabel!
    var BaylorIDValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var EmailLabel: UILabel!
    var BaylorEmailValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var PhoneNumberLabel: UILabel!
    var PhoneNumberValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var ModelNumberLabel: UILabel!
    var ModelNumberValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var SerialNumberLabel: UILabel!
    var SerialNumberValue : String!
    @IBOutlet var NotesLabel: UILabel!
    var NotesValue : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FirstNameLabel.text = FirstNameValue
        LastNameLabel.text = LastNameValue
        BaylorIDLabel.text = BaylorIDValue
        BaylorEmailLabel.text = BaylorEmailValue
        PhoneNumberLabel.text = PhoneNumberValue
        ModelNumberLabel.text = ModelNumberValue
        SerialNumberLabel.text = SerialNumberValue
        NotesLabel.text = NotesValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can access the fields/outlets from `prepare` (I could be thinking of another scenario). What I tend to do, is use a `struct` to wrap the data in and assign that to an optional variable in the destination.  When `viewDidLoad` is (finally) called, I check the state of that optional, if it's been set, I apply the values to the fields at that point

Comment: I would suggest you set breakpoints in `prepare` and `viewDidLoad` and step through your code to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify `prepare(for:sender:)` is called, e.g. using breakpoints or `print`/caveman debugging;
2. verify `ViewNewSummary.viewDidLoad()` is called, too;
3. verify `prepare` is called before `viewDidLoad`.

My suspicion is that `viewDidLoad` is called *before* `prepare(for:sender:)` is called; that'd make sense since you need an initialized view controller object to prepare the segue with.

So you will want to add `viewWillAppear(_:)` as a quick fix:

```
extension ViewNewSummary {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        FirstNameLabel.text = FirstNameValue
        LastNameLabel.text = LastNameValue
        BaylorIDLabel.text = BaylorIDValue
        BaylorEmailLabel.text = BaylorEmailValue
        PhoneNumberLabel.text = PhoneNumberValue
        ModelNumberLabel.text = ModelNumberValue
        SerialNumberLabel.text = SerialNumberValue
        NotesLabel.text = NotesValue
    }
}
```

If that doesn't scale well for all cases, you may want to look into property observers, like

```
var PhoneNumberValue : String! { 
    didSet {
        guard isViewLoaded else { return }
        PhoneNumberLabel.text = PhoneNumberValue
    }
}
```